# How to disallow bots that don't obey robots.txt?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, robots.txt, webapp2

I recently changed my [robots.txt](http://koolbusiness.com/robots.txt) to disallow bots from making expensive search API queries. They are allowed all other pages right now except the `/q?...` that is a search API query and expensive.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /q?

Sitemap: /sitemap.xml.gz
```

Now I'm still getting bots in my logs. Is it google or just "googlebot compatible"? How can I disallow bots completely from /q?

```
2014-10-18 21:04:23.474 /q?query=category%3D5030%20and%20cityID%3D4698187&o=4 200 261ms 7kb Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) module=default version=disallow
66.249.79.28 - - [18/Oct/2014:12:04:23 -0700] "GET /q?query=category%3D5030%20and%20cityID%3D4698187&o=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 8005 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"  ms=261 cpu_ms=108 cpm_usd=0.050895 app_engine_release=1.9.13 instance=00c61b117cdfd20321977d865dd08cef54e2fa
```

Can I blacklist specific bots according to their http headers in my request handler or in my `dos.yaml`if robots.txt can't do it? When I run this to look for matches, there are 50 matches last 2 hours:

`path:/q.* useragent:.*Googlebot.*`

The log rows look like this, looking like googlebot:

`2014-10-19 00:37:34.449 /q?query=category%3D1030%20and%20cityID%3D4752198&o=18 200 138ms 7kb Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) module=default version=disallow
66.249.79.102 - - [18/Oct/2014:15:37:34 -0700] "GET /q?query=category%3D1030%20and%20cityID%3D4752198&o=18 HTTP/1.1" 200 7965 - "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "www.classifiedsmarket.appspot.com" ms=138 cpu_ms=64 cpm_usd=0.050890 app_engine_release=1.9.13 instance=00c61b117c781458f46764c359368330c7d7fdc4`

Comment: Side note: You should provide the [full URL to the sitemap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14218476/1591669).

Comment: Did you add this `Disallow` line only recently? And/or did you target the Googlebot specifically before?

Comment: Yes, I saw that most of my application costs was from using the search API from `/q?...` and that the googlebot was performing searches. It seems a noticable decrease in request if I compare to earlier (app costs are down significalty since this change) but it is not gone completely. Googlebot has requested the new `/robots.txt` lately. It was only recently that I changed the `Disallow` from allowing. I was wondering if some other program could emulate googlebot and send the same http header and disregards robots.txt making queries and faking them as googlebot, or a compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every visitor/bot can claim to be `Googlebot/2.1` (by changing the [`User-Agent` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)).

You can [verify that it was the real Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en) with a reverse DNS lookup.

According to the IPs from your logs, it seems to have been the real bot. And your robots.txt is correct, too. So it should only be a matter of time until Google recognizes the new rule, after which all requests should stop.

Bots that don’t honor your robots.txt can of course be blocked from accessing the resources, but (depending on your criteria for identifying bots) this bears the risk of blocking human visitors, too.