# Sitemap reference in robots.txt for each TLD

Tags: internationalization, sitemap, host, robots.txt

We are using the robots.txt to reference our sitemap index file. 
Now we will release new, different countries. Our webseite under the TLD `.de` provides a robots.txt, containing a reference to our index file. The index files refers to different sitemaps containing our `.de` link in `loc` XML node. Other locales (eg. for `.fr`) are listed with `xhtml:link` below.

Example:

```
<url>
    <loc>https://xy.de/hallo</loc>
    <xhtml:link>https://xy.fr/hello</xhtml:link>
</url>
```

The question is now, should we add a robots.txt with a reference to our sitemap index to our `.fr` index too? 
Or might it is enough to place the reference only in the German `.de` robots.txt because the locations are described with alternative locations for each other locale? Or should we invert the `loc` XML node with the "current" locale? E.g. under `https://xy.fr/robots.txt` should there be a sitemap referenced with `.fr` links in the `loc` XML node?

Answer (score 1):

The [Sitemaps protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) doesn’t mention an `xhtml:link` element, so consumers following the protocol might ignore it.

As a sitemap [can only contain URLs from the same host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350541/1591669), and a robots.txt file also only works for its host, the typical way is to give each host its own robots.txt file which points to this host’s sitemap ([with an absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14218476/1591669)).

```
# robots.txt from http://fr.example/robots.txt
Sitemap: http://fr.example/sitemap.xml
```

```
# robots.txt from http://de.example/robots.txt
Sitemap: http://de.example/sitemap.xml
```

The sitemap can be hosted on a different host, but you still need to prove ownership via the robots.txt file (see  [Sitemaps & Cross Submits](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemaps_cross_submits)).