# Google Webmaster Tools is not accepting my sitemap

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

Few days ago I set robots.txt for my website which you find in below:

```
user-agent: *

Allow: /$

Disallow: /
```

Now I am facing some problem to submit my sitemap in Google Webmaster:

> We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.

I got this reply and also get:

> URL restricted by robots.txt

Now what can I do to submit my sitemap in Webmaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your robots.txt disallows accessing any URL except the root (`/`, e.g.: `http://example.com/`). So bots are (per your robots.txt) not allowed to crawl your sitemap.

You could add another `Allow` line (like below), but in general there is probably no point in having a sitemap if you disallow crawling all pages except the homepage.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Allow: /sitemap.xml$
Disallow: /
```

(I removed the empty lines, because they are not allowed inside a record.)

Note that you could also [link your sitemap from the robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759709/1591669).

Comment: It is really very helpful for me.. Thanks for your kind help.