# Creating a sitemapindex file using sitemap.txt

Tags: seo, sitemap, plaintext

Using the XML sitemap, we can create a `sitemap.xml` file:

```xml
<sitemapindex>
 <sitemap>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/0.xml</loc>
 </sitemap>
 <sitemap>
  <loc>https://www.example.com/1.xml</loc>
 </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

But how do we achieve the same using `sitemap.txt` file? Do we include it in `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

The Sitemaps protocol doesn’t support sitemap index files for the text format.

You have to provide multiple sitemap files (*[Other Sitemap formats](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#otherformats) →  Text file*):

> Each text file can contain a maximum of 50,000 URLs and must be no larger than 50MB (52,428,800 bytes). If you site includes more than 50,000 URLs, **you can separate the list into multiple text files and add each one separately**.

Then specify all of the files when [informing search engines about your sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759709/1591669), e.g., in your robots.txt:

```
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap_1.txt

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap_2.txt

Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap_3.txt
```

Comment: but what you have provide is text format file which directs to text format files? So if all sitemap files listed in robots.txt it is posible to use only text formats?