# Dynamic Sitemap URL in robots.txt file

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, google-search-console

I have the following content in my robots.txt file:

```
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap.php
```

Is it ok to have the `sitemap` in robots.txt as `.php` file instead of `.xml` as I generate it dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A consumer (like a search engine bot) **can’t know** if a file is static or dynamically generated, it could only guess (e.g., based on the response time, HTTP response headers, or the URL design).
You could have a static file named `sitemap.php`, and you could have a dynamically generated file named `sitemap.xml`.

And a consumer **doesn’t need to know**. What matters is the content of the file, not how the file was/is created, [not its URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30759709/1591669).

In any case, make sure to send the correct `Content-Type` for this file. Some servers automatically select a content type based on the filename extension, which would fail with `.php`, so you might have to set it explicitly.