# Difference between links with different case

Tags: url, hyperlink, seo, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

How does Google view links with all uppercase?

Is this the same for Google:

```
example.net/LogIn.html

example.net/LOGIN.html

example.net/login.html
```

I need to redesign an old site with uppercase on links, but I don't want to lose Google rank.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP URL paths [are **case-sensitive**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/51901/17633).

Live example: The following two URLs only differ in `O` vs. `o` and they lead to different pages:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

So the first assumption of every conforming consumer should be that `/LogIn.html`, `/LOGIN.html`, and `/login.html` could lead to different resources.

Consumers might use various signals to decide if that’s really the case or if the server simply accepts any case (e.g., by detecting duplicate content). But if you have such a server, you would [ideally use 301 redirects to point to the canonical variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835383/1591669), or, [if that’s not possible](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/54819/17633), the `canonical` link type (you might also want to use this one in addition to the redirect).